# Change of Variables Formula in Aliprantis & Burkinshaw's Principles of Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

On page 393 in Section 40, they give their proof of the CoVF and state "It follows that the formula is true for step functions, and then by a *simple continuity argument,* for each $f\in L_1(W).$" I understand how it holds for step functions, but can someone please provide the details of the simple continuity argument? Below is their proof. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is non-negative  the result follows from the case of simple functions and Monotne Convergence Theorem. The general case follows by applying the result to $f^{+}$ and $f^{-}$ since these are integrable and $f^{+}\circ T |J_T|$ and  $f^{-}\circ T |J_T|$ are also integrable.

Comment: Thank you. Is this what is meant by a "simple continuity argument"?

Comment: Yes. This argument  is quite standard. @LP

Comment: I understand this argument, but I don't see the "continuity" part of it.